# image alignment with set points-python

Tags: python, image, alignment

I've been looking for a way to align at least two images in Python.
 There are some very nice scripts out there, but I'd like a script that accepts the coordinates of a point in one image and use these coordinates to align the second(or more) image.
I'v been reading about phase correlation algorithms but I'd appreciate some help on how to use the coordinates  of a user defined  point.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you intend to "align" the second image, and what does the user-given point represent?  Is it just an offset indicating where the upper-left corner (or center, or...) of the second image should be placed?  Something else?  What would be an illegal value for that point?  (For instance, is it OK if it's outside the boundaries of the first image?)  It's really unclear what your goal is, especially your expected inputs and outputs.

Comment: Hi Kevin

the user defined pointed would be a feature on the image e.g. somebody's nose or the base of an antenna in a building. 
  So if the base of the antenna is at coordinates (x1,y1) I would like to find the coordinates of the base in the second image(x2,y2) and align the images such that (x1,y1)=(x2,y2).

My input would be (x1,y2).

Thank you for trying to help me.
Alex

Comment: I don't do much with images, so I suspect your question is beyond my abilities.  Just to be clear, though:  Is the part you're trying to figure out the aligning of the two images given the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), or figuring out yourself where to place (x2, y2) in the second image given only (x1, y1) by the user?  (You said your input was (x1, y2)... was that a typo?)

Comment: Yes this was a typo!
I am interested in the second case "figuring out yourself where to place (x2, y2) in the second image given only (x1, y1) by the user".

Comment: Definitely beyond my ability to help, then.